# Error while import .LDF to AD LDS instance

Tags: active-directory, ldif

I have installed the new instance by following [these](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770623.aspx) instructions.

Now I trying to import the sample.LDF file which I have downloaded from [here](http://pastebin.com/B6qVh1AE).

But while imporing

```
ldifde -i -f MS-Sample.LDF -s localhost:389 -j C:\Desktop\Log
```

I am getting these error

```
Connecting to "localhost:389"

Logging in as current user using SSPI

Importing directory from file "MS-Sample.LDF"

Loading entries
1: ou=People,dc=jbpm,dc=org

dn: ou=People,dc=jbpm,dc=org
Attribute 0) objectclass:top organizationalUnit
Attribute 1) ou:People

Add error on entry starting on line 1: Already Exists

The server side error is: 0x2071 An attempt was made to add an object to the directory    with a name that is already in use.

The extended server error is:

00002071: UpdErr: DSID-03050328, problem 6005 (ENTRY_EXISTS), data 0


0 entries modified successfully.

An error has occurred in the program
```

But Don not know the exact error. Please Help